# What is the difference between primary and volume currents in electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, medical-physics

What is the basic difference between the two currents and how each is contributing to the magnetic field at source and the surface?

Comment: What is the configuration of these currents, what is the source and what is the surface? Are you talking about electrophysiology?

Comment: The source is the cardiac currents at heart and surface is torso.

Comment: Thanks. I think it would be good to include this scenario in your question, which seems to be less about electrodynamics, than a special (biological) application. In a very, very crude approximation, one could approximate the heart as a small voltage source, that is embedded in a conducting cylinder. So you would have to solve the Laplace equation in a cylinder to get an idea about the current distribution (which, intuitively, would be similar to a squashed dipole).